# Meaning of "Es bestehen keine Vorerkrankungen"

Tags: passive

I understand in the sentence
"*Es bestehen keine Vorerkrankungen.*" the "*Es*" is used in passive - the so called "passives Es".

Yet I never really understood it. In my lay-man German I would have written "*Es gibt keine Vorerkrankungen.*"

Can someone please explain the passive here?

Comment: There is no passive here. "geben" and "bestehen" are used here as *impersonal verbs*.

Comment: @Roland: Perhaps we're using different definitions, but to me, the grammatical subject of an impersonal verb is *es*, which means the verb would be conjugated *besteht* rather than *bestehen*. I *think* this is a case of *es* being used as a placeholder; for whatever reason the author wanted to stress *bestehen* over *Vorerkrankungen*. In any case, it's not the passive voice; there's no promotion of object to subject.

Answer (score 2):

To clear up a confusion: passive voice in German uses "werden" and a participle ("Es *wird* überall viel *geredet*."), so this isn't passive voice.

I've never heard the term "passives Es", and Google finds nothing, so I don't know for which uses of "es" it is used.

The term from German grammar that comes to mind here is "unpersönliche Verben" (impersonal verbs). These are verbs that need no "real" subject and go with "es" as a meaningless stand-in for the subject instead.

Examples für "unpersönliche Verben":

> Wie geht es dir?
> Es regnet.
> Es gibt heute einen Nachtisch. *(Note that "einen Nachtisch" is accusative case here)*
> Es gibt keine Vorerkrankungen. *(also accusative case)*

So you could be mislead into thinking that

> "Es bestehen keine Vorerkrankungen."

was just another one of these examples, but that's actually not the case. Unlike "Es gibt,", "es" is not the grammatical subject of the sentence here, which is "keine Vorerkrankungen" (nominative case). "Es" is just a stand-in, if you will, for the general state of the world, without any real meaning. You could rearrange the sentence to:

> "Keine Vorerkrankungen bestehen."

and lose the *es* completely. The variant with "es bestehen..." just sounds  more fluent. Since the subject "keine Vorerkrankungen" is plural, the verb form is 3rd person plural, the "es" has no weight in  that.

Comment: A placeholder-es can appear in an  impersonal passive sentence: *Es wird zu viel geraucht*. But this does not apply here.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for explaining in detail